# Use of Replace in SQL when Listagg function is used that will output distinct variables

Tags: sql, mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following query:

```
select distinct
a.product_desc as "Product",
a.PRODUCT_ID  as "Product ID",
(a.START_DATE ::timestamp) as "Start Date",
LISTAGG(DISTINCT a.location, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.location DESC) AS "Location" 
from table as a
```

This results in the following output:

[image: Current Output]

What I am looking to do is do a replace (or which ever other way) the Country in Location with the Continent instead. Not only to replace it with the continent, but I do NOT want the continents to repeat.

Here is a mock of my desired output:

[image: Desired Output]

As you can see the row with Carrots, the Location has only North America listed once in the desired output, even though North America has 2 location entries for Carrots.

What I am looking to do is do a replace (or which ever other way) the Country in Location with the Continent instead. Not only to replace it with the continent, but I do NOT want the continents to repeat.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: How are you mapping countries to continents? If this information is in a table then you just need to join to it, get the continent and listagg that

Comment: @NickW it is not mapped anywhere or stored anywhere in the tables. That is why I was thinking of a replace.

Comment: Given that there are nearly 200 countries in the world that’s a very large REPLACE statement. Put the data in a table and then the query becomes very simple plus it’s easy to manage any mapping changes

Comment: Hi @NickW, I understand what you are saying, but I don't have control over that. Plus currently the list is not that long. I would like to figure out how to  best approach this regardless. I appreciate your help!